# Headless service for blue green or A/B deployment

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

How can we make headless service work in case of blue-green or A/B deployment?

The service id moves across when we do the switch but how can we make application aware of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to create blue/green deployment using the [headless service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services). This is, beacuse:

> Sometimes you don't need load-balancing and a single Service IP. In this case, you can create what are termed "headless" Services, by explicitly specifying  `"None"`  for the cluster IP (`.spec.clusterIP`).

However, if you want to create a blue/green deployment, you need a network traffic control tool to switch between pods. You can also read more [here](https://linkerd.io/2.10/features/traffic-split/):

> If working with headless services, traffic splits cannot be retrieved. Linkerd reads service discovery information based off the target IP address, and if that happens to be a pod IP address then it cannot tell which service the pod belongs to.

Comment: Thanks ... Even I had the same understanding and wanted to see what the community thinks about it.